# Что делает конструкция «onClick='bm_table.submit()'»?

Tags: php

Есть функция, которая отображает ссылки:

```
function display_user_menu()
{
  // display the menu options on this page
?>
<hr />
<a href="member.php">Home</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="add_bm_form.php">Add BM</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
<?php
  // only offer the delete option if bookmark table is on this page
  global $bm_table;
  if($bm_table==true)
    echo "<a href='#' onClick='bm_table.submit();'>Delete BM</a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;"; 
  else
    echo "<font color='#cccccc'>Delete BM</font>&nbsp;|&nbsp;"; 
?>
<a href="change_passwd_form.php">Change password</a>
<br />
<a href="recommend.php">Recommend URLs to me</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a> 
<hr />

<?php
}
```

и страница в которой отображаются эти ссылки

[image]

Не понятно смысл конструкции

```
onClick='bm_table.submit();'
```

и ее назначение в приведенном куске кода. Объясните пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде странички наверняка есть форма с id bm_table, что-то типа:

```
<form id="bm_table">
***
</form>
```

Так вот клик по ссылке, инициирует отправку формы.

Comment: @Павел Вершинин у меня также есть переменная

    global $bm_table;
или к ней эта конструкция явно не относится? А такая форма правда с `name=bm_table` действительно есть (а не с `id` и по смыслу вяжется).

Comment: $bm_table это переменная PHP, логический переключатель (boolean) используется вашим PHP скриптом, для определения, можно или нельзя показывать ссылку Delete BM. 
А bm_table это переменная JavaScript, по всей видимости содержащая ссылку на объект странички. Тобишь ничего общего в них нет.